# Not receiving emails from contact us and job application plugin to all email addresses on our domain

Tags: plugins

Our web developers have setup and installed Craft on a VPS for a new website. When we fill out the contact us or Job application email recipient details; the emails never reach our email addresses, they also don't reach our messagelabs mail filter.
If I add another email address or a gmail account the emails are received just fine. I'm drawing a blank as to what the fault can be.

On MX Lookup blacklist check our domain and public IP are all clear. I've configured an A record to the IP of the VPS on our hosted DNS service. The VPS support have tested emailing us from the VPS (not the CMS) and emails come through.

Are there logs for Craft, is there a way I can see what's going on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

D

Comment: Under settings and email, are the details entered there correctly? You can also change the protocol for email, the default being phpmail I believe. You can also run a test on this page, which should tell you if it is working with Craft. If this works, and your page forms don't, the problem could be with your template code/plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the email settings are correct as when I enter a gmail address or another work email address from a different domain I receive the email. It just seems to be when the recipient is on clients domain. I ran the test and it says email sent successfully.  Does the Email protocol matter?

Comment: Seems you will need to dig deeper alas. Brad or the community could answer the protocol query properly.

Comment: I don't think this is Craft related. If it's only for one domain, then it's probably something with that domain. Most likely the mailserver on the webserver still thinking it needs to process mail for that domain locally. Usually a control panel setting. Also see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As replied to the support ticket: Is the web server setup to handle emails locally for the domain (local delivery)? Your mail servers seem to live elsewhere so that could explain why you don't receive them yet gmail works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help with this. I reached a solution and as you suggested the fault was not with Craft. The VPS provider had blocked our whole domain by name after a few failed SSH login attempts. The SSH access was opened up again but our domain name was still blocked. After more work with the VPS support the VPS host added our domain to the remote recipients list and then emails from all craft plugins were being received. 
Thanks all for your help and suggestions.